# What's the simplest way to backup a table's values and restore them if needed?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am working on some scripts that will modify many records in a table if they meet certain conditions.

In case my script is wrong, I need a quick and easy way to revert back to the original values of a table.

Currently, I am doing the following

- Right click on the database
- Tasks ---> Generate Scripts
- Then I select Drop - Create with data or data + schema

This never works because the table I need to backup has foreign key constraints.

I just want to generate a script that wipes the values and inserts the old ones to a table.  Does anyone know a simple trick for this?

Comment: Why don't you wrap your update in a transaction, check that it's ok and then commit the transaction

Comment: Is it an oversimplification to just `select * into myTestTable from YourActualTable` and test your script against the test table?